# How to handle versioning in sql with single query

Tags: mysql

Each Lead put data into pre_order_quotation table with a new version each time.
I am trying to get row count of all quotation by a lead & add 1 to it to get the version of new entry of quotation .
Was trying to achieve it in single query

```
insert into pre_order_quotation (lead_id,version,created_at,updated_at,file_name) values (1405,(select count(*) from pre_order_quotation where lead_id = 1405)+1,'2020-08-22 12:13:51','2020-08-22 12:13:51','dummy-5f410bffbcc80.pdf')
```

But i am getting the following error :

`You can't specify target table 'pre_order_quotation' for update in FROM clause`

How can i achieve it in single query?

Answer (score 1):

Bury the increment a bit deeper..

```
insert into pre_order_quotation (lead_id,version,created_at,updated_at,file_name) 
values (1405,
(select cnt from (select count(*) + 1 cnt from pre_order_quotation where lead_id = 1405) s ),
'2020-08-22 12:13:51','2020-08-22 12:13:51','dummy-5f410bffbcc80.pdf');
```

Comment: Any specific reason why it dosen't work on the first level ?